interstitialIsUnavailable() in FairBid iOS SDK
I'm using DT FairBid iOS SDK, version:- 3.49.1. With AdMob as mediator. But interstitial getting unavailable everyTime.

Initialisation

 func application(_ application: UIApplication, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions: [UIApplication.LaunchOptionsKey: Any]?) -> Bool {
        
        
        let options = FYBStartOptions()
        options.autoRequestingEnabled = true
        options.logLevel = .verbose
        FairBid.start(withAppId: AdvConsts.App_id, options: options)
}


Interstitial starting

class HomeViewController:  FYBInterstitialDelegate {


    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        

        FYBInterstitial.delegate = self
        self.intersitialRequest()

    }

   func intersitialRequest(){
        

        let placeId = AdvConsts.Interstetial_id
        FYBInterstitial.enableAutoRequesting(placeId)
        FYBInterstitial.request(placeId) 
    }

    func showInterstitial(){
        
        DispatchQueue.main.async {
            
            if (FYBInterstitial.isAvailable(AdvConsts.Interstetial_id)) { //Getting Unavailable, so unable to display interstitial.
                let showOptions = FYBShowOptions()
                showOptions.viewController = (UIApplication.shared.delegate as? AppDelegate)?.window?.rootViewController
                FYBInterstitial.show(AdvConsts.Interstetial_id, options: showOptions)
                self.videoCount = val
            }
         }

    }
    
   //MARK: - Delegate Methods

    func interstitialIsAvailable(_ placementId: String) {
        print("->\(placementId)",#function)
    }
    
    func interstitialIsUnavailable(_ placementId: String) {
        print("->\(placementId)",#function)
    }
    
    func interstitialDidShow(_ placementId: String, impressionData: FYBImpressionData) {
        print("->\(placementId)",#function)
    }
    
    func interstitialDidFail(toShow placementId: String, withError error: Error, impressionData: FYBImpressionData) {
        print("->\(placementId)",#function,"\n Error:- \(error)")
    }
    
    func interstitialDidClick(_ placementId: String) {
        print("->\(placementId)",#function)
    }
    
    func interstitialDidDismiss(_ placementId: String) {
        intersitialRequest()
        print("->\(placementId)",#function)
    }
  
    func interstitialWillRequest(_ placementId: String, withRequestId requestId: String) {
        print("->\(placementId)",#function,"\n requestId:- \(requestId)")
    }

}


Now the problem is whenever i Tried to request for interstitial, It's getting unavailable. And calls 'interstitialIsUnavailable()' method of delegate.

I've tried to remove old placement of interstitial and recreated new one, but it's also not working
